# $(".elem[data-name='+var+']")

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

```
$(".singleMember[data-id='+id+']");
```

`id` is a variable, it doesn't work this way, no errors.
How'd you select this?

Comment: $(".singleMember[data-id='"+id+"']");

Comment: thanks, can you post that as an answer, eventhough it was hard to see :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here goes. I think you had an issue with string constants and using both " and '. So, I added the id to your string within '.

```
$(".singleMember[data-id='"+id+"']");
```